# Having issue with my java program?

Tags: java

**EDIT 1:**

program should output this:
java CircleBugs 1.2 0.6 r = 1.2,  t = 0.6 c = 7.5398223686155035 a = 4.523893421169302 x = 0.9904027378916139, y = 0.6775709680740424

My error:

Exception in thread "main" 
             java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
             at debug.Debug.main(Debug.java:24)
             C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor- 
             snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
             BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I am having an issue debugging this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double t = Double.parseDouble(args[0]); 
    int r = Integer.parseInt(args[]); 

    System.out.println("r = " + r + ",  t = " + t); //Added the ";" to close the line of code

    double c = 2 * Math.PI * r;         
            double A = Math.PI * r * r; 

    double x = r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(t));      //fixed    
            double y = r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(t));     //fixed

    System.out.println("c = " + c ); 
    System.out.println("A = " + A ); 
    System.out.println("x = " + x + ", " + "y = " + y );  
   }
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: `import static java.lang.Math.*;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `args` array is empty, and is causing this error. 
The problem is that you don't give your program any inputs, so you try to `parseDouble(args[0])` on an empty array.

Use something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double t = sc.nextDouble();
int r = sc.nextInt();
```

Also you should use the methods like:

```
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(t))
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(t))
```

Comment: but im getting this error // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at debug.Debug.main(Debug.java:20)

Comment: And what is your input? You're probably not feeding your program any input, and args is empty.

Comment: what goes in there then the completed program should output: java CircleBugs 1.2 0.6 r = 1.2,  t = 0.6 c = 7.5398223686155035 a = 4.523893421169302 x = 0.9904027378916139, y = 0.6775709680740424

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Still running into these errors and it keeps leading back to the parse lines // double t = Double.parseDouble(args[0]); 
    int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0])

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: I am using blueJ but even in netbeans ide i am running into this error

Comment: You need to give your program some sort of input. I wrote you an example in my edited answer and then you can give your program inupt via console.

Comment: Alright i have added the code you suggested C + P changed the variable names though. Now the program is getting input from the user but right after its done it crashed and doesnt output the numbers needed

Comment: So you need to update your question for new information, but keep in mind that this site is not for debugging your programs. Also please accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

When using `Double.parseDouble(args[0])` it assumes that you are passing values in command line for this arg values otherwise the array is empty(so you get indexoutofboundexception while calling the first element from an empty array). So just change code like this

```
double t = Double.parseDouble(args[0]); 
int r = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

And in command line execute this.

```
java test 5 4 //5 in place of t and 4 in place of r
```

I saved my file as test.java so replace test with your file name and run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` methods.

```
double x = r * Math.cos(t);
double y = r * Math.sin(t);
```